# SQL Update Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Suppose i have a table with columns: Approved, Joining_Date, Period.

Approve-String, Joining_Date-DateTime, Period-Integer.
Now I want to update the Approved column value to yes if the difference between today's date and the Joining_Date column is greater than Period column. How can this be accomplished in a single query? Something like:

```
"UPDATE table_name SET Approved='Yes' WHERE (SYSDATE-Joining_Date>Period)"
```

I am using ASP.NET 4 and MS-SQL 2008 Express in VS 2010. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Period` is in days:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Approved='Yes' 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Joining_Date, GETDATE()) > Period
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out DATEDIFF:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Approved='Yes'
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, Joining_Date, GETDATE()) > Period
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE table_name set Approved = 'Yes' 
 WHERE DateDiff(dd, JoiningDate, getdate()) > Period
```

Assumes Period is stored as integer number of days.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx for other examples if Period is not days.